# More DOM elements creating performance issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dom, reflow

We created an application using asp.net mvc, javascript and jQuery (hosted in local machine). The base design is, we kept all the HMTL elements in the DOM object (browser) instead of destroying, by hiding and showing the HTML pages when the user navigates from one page to other pages.

Day by day our application is growing. Earlier I didn't see any performance issues in my project. But nowadays if I am navigating one page to other page taking long time. Today I checked DOM elements in my page, it is crossed more than 20,000.

Questions:

---

Hiding/showing HTML pages is a better design than destroying and re-creating?

DOM manipulation from javascript with 20,000 DOM object, what is the impact of performance in term of reflow and reprint?

Comment: DOM manipulation is expensive. If you're using jQuery to build/destroy ~20,000 elements, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: what is the maximum limit of DOM object I can maintain in my single page? somewhere I read it is 700 to 1000.

Comment: I recommend AJAX pagination of your elements.  It's kind of a compromise of both worlds.  You have a faster call than page load, but it's not quite as fast as just hiding and showing (unless you have 20,000ish elements on page)

Comment: Let say we have 4 tabs, each tab I am loading one page. If user moving one page to other page we are hiding the div instead of destroying. I knew this is wrong way of implementation. But I am new to the team, before I am going to explain this to my technical specialist, I need more information about reflow and what is the impact of reflow if DOM has more element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for reference, the [single-page HTML5 spec itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html) has 109k DOM Elements (and even more DOM Nodes) at the time of this writing.

> Hide/Show the HTML pages is good design instead of destroying and re-created?

That largely depends on whether it is *necessary* (e.g. because re-creating removed sections would be slow) and/or *likely* (user interaction frequently causes hidden sections to be displayed again).

There are several things that can slow you down

a) garbage collection. more nodes = mode objects for the garbage collector to traverse. In principle a modern garbage collector should be able to deal with many long-lived objects by stuffing them into old regions which then don't get touched again, but not all browsers have state-of-the-art GCs.

b) reflow events/dom queries/traversal operations etc.

c) javascript code that scales badly with the document size. some O(n²) algorithms might creep into complex applications. Callbacks triggering further callbacks and such.

There is not much you can do about a) if you don't want to cut down on your DOM tree. But b) and c) can be optimized in several ways:

- detach subtrees from the document and keep them in javascript/document fragments, this way anything traversing the document tree won't have to deal with them
- do not interleave actions that

  1. read the layout state (such as getting computed CSS properties, bounding rectangles, offsets etc.)
  2. write to the DOM in any manner or trigger events
     Execute reads and writes separately, in bulk to minimize the number of reflows
- optimize hotspots in your javascript

But those are just general guidelines. You should profile your application to figure out what is eating CPU time, whether you're dominated by the GC, javascript execution or paint events.

Comment: **Just for reference, the single-page HTML5 spec itself has 109k DOM Elements.**  Yes, I agree. but if you look at the page, It doesn't have any java-script manipulation. basically this is static page. In my scenario is different, take a example of busy site like share market.